# Unable to get photos to upload to Android app?

Tags: bug, android-app

I am having a problem uploading a couple photos of my lilac bush.

Every time I hit the camera button, the picture will start uploading, then I get a red prompt at the top that says "There is a problem uploading that photo. Try again?"

I was able to get one photo to upload, but that's all.

Can you tell me what is wrong?

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: samsung
- Device Model: SPH-L710

  - OS Version: 4.4.2 (L710VPUCOJ1)

Comment: Hmm. I think uploading photos is a privilege earned at some rep level. But since you got one to upload, that doesn't seem to be an issue. Given that the system gets all the way to the end of the upload, then rejects the image, maybe it's a file format issue? Can you post the photos to another site (say, imgur.com) and add links to this question? That way we can experiment for ourselves.

Comment: I think there is a limit on new users uploading more than one picture but I have not been able to find where that is documented.

Comment: I was able to upload an album. Hopefully others can see it besides me. Lol. Thankyou very much!! I will keep imgur on my "go to" list.

Comment: @PolyGeo I thought I saw something like that also...if it's there, it should be found at http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user, but it's not listed there. Oh well.

Comment: I got it done. Thanks everyone!!!

Comment: PolyGeo...I think you're right about only one photo allowed for new users. That seems to be my experience. But I can't find anywhere that declares this on this stack exchange site.